# Making ggplot geom_boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

**Boxplot in ggplot**

```
df %>%
  mutate(Bezettingsgraad = Bezetting_gem / Capaciteit *100 ) %>% 
  group_by(Stadion)
```

**Code for the boxplot**

```
df %>%
  mutate(Bezettingsgraad = Bezetting_gem / Capaciteit *100 ) %>% 
  group_by(Provincie) %>% 
  
ggplot(Provincie, aes(x=Provincie, y=Bezetting_gem, color=dose)) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

In the image you see in yellow the rows that are being used
[image]

**Error**
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before the mapping aesthetics you have included the variable Provincie in the place where your data should be . Besides you are already piping your data into your ggplot call via the %>% operator.
Try deleting Provincie